# How to show not full sized video on IOS while playing movie in HTML5 video element?

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I'm trying to play  on iPhone's Safari so i can have website menu bar below the video but once i click on play button iOS opens video in full screenmode with iOS controls.

Thanks

Comment: You can't. IOS doesn't support embedding video in browser frame.

Comment: I've seen web application doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work on the iPad, however on the iPhone the video will automatically go full screen